# XSLT - extract a string within brackets

Tags: xslt, text, xslt-1.0

I have a node

```
<example> 
     Test1 (10) test2 (20) ... 
</example>
```

And i need to transform this to:

```
<example> 
     Test1 <number>10</number> test2 <number>(20)</number>
</example>
```

Therefore i need a function that will extract all the text between ( and ) recursively. The bad news is that i need it in XSLT version 1.0.

Comment: In your output, 10 has lost the surrounding brackets, while 20 still has them. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive template called by name like the following. Note that recursive templates can be problematic if the recursion depth is too high. If your input text contains a couple of thousand parens, it's possible that the XSLT processor crashes with a stack overflow. These errors are extremely hard to debug. If you're only dealing with a handful of parens, the recursive approach should be OK.

Also note that my example doesn't handle nested parens.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="example">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="convert-parens">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="convert-parens">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, '(')">
            <xsl:variable name="after" select="substring-after($string, '(')"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($after, ')')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, '(')"/>
                    <number>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($after, ')')"/>
                    </number>
                    <xsl:call-template name="convert-parens">
                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($after, ')')"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you not avoid the nested `xsl:choose` by combining the two tests into one?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, at the expense of another call to `substring-after`.

Answer (score 0):

With a [xsl:analyze-string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-analyze-string) with a regex, the code can be more simple:

```
  <xsl:template match="example">
    <element>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="text()" regex="[(][0-9][0-9][)]">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <number>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,2,2)"/>
          </number>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>    
    </element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT 1.0, and OP says expressly "*The bad news is that i need it in XSLT version 1.0.*". Your answer requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Yes, it is not implemented in XSLT 1.0.. Error when reading too fast a request